# Get element position in html source

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, lxml

I'm using lxml to extract all the URLs from a HTML source, but I also want to get the position of that URL. The URL first character position.

Right now I have something like this:

```py
import requests
import lxml.html

r = requests.get(url)
soup = lxml.html.fromstring(req.text)

links = []
for element, attribute, link, pos in soup.iterlinks():
    try:
        links.append((link, req.text.index(link)))
    except:
        # can't find link in text because '&amp;' gets resolved to '&'
        pass
```

Is there a better way to do this ? Not sure how good is this solution, performance wise.

Does LXML keeps the position of the element somewhere ? I know it saves the sourceline where the element was found, but I can't find anything regarding the start position of the element.

http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#sourceline

Comment: Do you mean if the whole document was treated as a string, your trying to find the index into that string of a particular element?

Comment: Yes. In my case the link/URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even if not very elegant, a regex from the URL would do the job:

```
import re
p = re.compile(link)
start_position = p.search(data).start()
```

If indeed you need to find at once all the positions for the same link:

`p = re.compile(link)
positions = [asd.start() for asd in p.finditer(req.text)]`

Hope it helps

Comment: How regex would work when there is a modification in the URL?